# How to decode URL query parameters with Kotlinx Serialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, url, serialization

How can I deserialize the URL "https://example.com?title=My+Title&description=My+Description" into the Kotlin object below using [KotlinX Serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html) in an Android app?

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class MyRecord(
  val title: String,
  val description: String
)
```

I found [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/84d4af04a688286ad1b51a72130ccda691caff75/docs/basic-serialization.md?plain=1#L115) for JSON deserialization but not for decoding URL encoded query parameters.

Comment: Why do you expect `kotlinx.serialization` to have that feature?

Comment: Because it is the reference Kotlin library for serialization. If such a feature is nonexistent nor planned in the library, it would also be interesting to know what is the best alternative to use on Android as of today to map URL query params into a Kotlin data class object.

Comment: URL parsing and serialization are different things. Webservers and clients may use both, but that's about it. May I suggest a web library such as Ktor?

Comment: I already use KotlinX Serialization and prefer to avoid an extra dependency. If it can't handle URL query params I will try to encode them into JSON and then decode that.

Comment: The `java.net.URL` class already has this feature.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I’m not aware of how to use java.net.URL to deserialize into a bespoke Kotlin data class.